# How can I create a master branch based off of a gh-pages branch?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a Jekyll theme that only has the branch `gh-pages`. I have completely customized the theme by pushing all my changes to that `gh-pages` branch. And now I wonder can I create a master branch from that `gh-pages` branch, and if I can, how would I do it?

I hope my question make sense because I am new to git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new local `master` branch based on the local `gh-pages` branch, you can use these commands:

```
git checkout gh-pages     # switch to the gh-pages branch
git branch -d master      # delete current (old) local master branch
git checkout -b master    # create new master from gh-pages and switch to it
```

Keep in mind that the second command will delete your local `master` branch to make room for the new one you wish to create.  So if you already have a local `master` branch you should make sure you really want to replace it.

If you want to create a new local `master` branch based on the *remote* `gh-pages` branch, you can use these commands:

```
git checkout gh-pages                     # switch to the gh-pages branch
git branch -d master                      # delete current (old) local master branch
git checkout -b master origin/gh-pages    # create new master from gh-pages
```

Comment: Thank you Tim Biegeleisenfor for your response, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry @Tim Biegeleisen, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have the `gh-pages` branch checked out to the latest commit:

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

Then create a new `master` branch based on the current branch:

```
git checkout -b master
```

Now if you only wanted the `master` branch locally, you're done. If you want it on the origin as well (on GitHub), push it like this:

```
git push origin master
```

---

Afterwards, if you want to delete the `gh-pages` branch locally, run:

```
git branch -d gh-pages
```

Then if you want to delete the `gh-pages` branch from remote (GitHub), run:

```
git push origin :gh-pages
```

Comment: Thanks Maximillian Laumeister for taking your time to answer my question.